# How do I print HTML code with indentantion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a layout page with the components that I'm using in a project for other people use the same design. My ideia is to let my script get my innerHTML code and print it for the user as a text;

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/pedro-gon-alves-the-sasster/pen/rEwOLp).

So far, I have this:

```js
// Get all divs with the ".topic" class and returns a list of it
// @return list | array()
function getTopicList() {

  // Create the list
  let list = [];

  // Populate the list
  $('.topic').map(function() {
    list.push($(this));
  });

  // Returns the list
  return list;

}

// Set the example code inside a "code" tag
// @param topic       | jquery object
// @param exampleCode | string
function setExampleCode(topic, exampleCode) {

  // Create a "code" tag inside the selected div
  $(topic).append('<code></code>');

  // Set the example's code inside the "code" tag
  $(topic).find('code').text(exampleCode);

}

// Get the HTML code inside the div as a string
// @param topic | jquery object
function generateExampleCode(topic) {

  // Get the HTML code as string
  let exampleCode = $(topic).children('.example').html();

  // Calls a function to append the code as a string into the div
  setExampleCode(topic, exampleCode);

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Get a list of all the divs that have the ".topic" class
  let topicList = getTopicList();

  // Get the HTML code of all the ".topic" divs
  topicList.map(generateExampleCode);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Buttons -->

<div class="topic white z-depth-1 u-padding-20">

  <h5>Buttons</h5>

  <p class="u-margin-20-0">Materialize buttons.</p>

  <div class="example grey lighten-3 u-padding-20 u-margin-20-0 u-overflow-hidden u-box-shadow-inset-1">

    <button class="btn left">Button</button>
    <button class="btn left"><i class="material-icons left">add</i>Button</button>
    <button class="btn left"><i class="material-icons right">add</i>Button</button>

  </div>

</div>
```

And my result is the following:

[image: example]

My expected result is:

[image: expected result]

I know that I can manipulate the string and replace the "<" for "`&lt;`" and the ">" for "`&gt;`", but is it the only way to do it? Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: *"is it the only way to do it?"* If the content isn't previously formatted, I think the answer is **yes**. How your code will *guess* the format ?

Comment: What about using `<pre>`? or just use a formatting script?

Comment: @VLAZ I can use the <pre> tag but it still requires me to replace manually the "<" and ">" chars and to rewrite the code inside the tag

Comment: @PedroGonçalves that's because you want to use `innerHTML` for some reason. Why? `textContent` (or event the bastardisation `innerText`) would do that for you.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Can't I use the indention that my code already have?

Comment: @PedroGonçalves sure, that is what I mean. If it is preformatted, you can use tag `<code>` or `<pre>`. They already has properties to keep format.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown but isn't it bad? I mean, what if I need to change something in a component? Wouldn't it be necessary to chance the code twice?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown OH nonoonoon I'm sorry, now I understant. For some reason the <pre> tag works in the codepen but not in my local, now I'm trying to understant why.

Answer (score 2):

would it not be appropriate to use "pre" tag like.

```
    function setExampleCode(topic, exampleCode) {
    // Create a "code" tag inside the selected div
    $(topic).append('<code><pre></pre></code>');

    // Set the example's code inside the "code" tag
    $(topic).find('pre').text(exampleCode);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all you need is some CSS?

```
code {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

[Working codepen from your example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjqdeX)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "pre" element when displaying text with unusual formatting, or some sort of computer code. [HTML pre Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

```js
// Get all divs with the ".topic" class and returns a list of it
// @return list | array()
function getTopicList() {

  // Create the list
  let list = [];

  // Populate the list
  $('.topic').map(function() {
    list.push($(this));
  });

  // Returns the list
  return list;

}

// Set the example code inside a "code" tag
// @param topic       | jquery object
// @param exampleCode | string
function setExampleCode(topic, exampleCode) {

  // Create a "code" tag inside the selected div
  $(topic).append('<pre></pre>');

  // Set the example's code inside the "code" tag
  $(topic).find('pre').text((exampleCode));

}

// Get the HTML code inside the div as a string
// @param topic | jquery object
function generateExampleCode(topic) {

  // Get the HTML code as string
  let exampleCode = $(topic).children('.example').html();

  // Calls a function to append the code as a string into the div
  setExampleCode(topic, exampleCode);

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Get a list of all the divs that have the ".topic" class
  let topicList = getTopicList();

  // Get the HTML code of all the ".topic" divs
  topicList.map(generateExampleCode);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Buttons -->

<div class="topic white z-depth-1 u-padding-20">

  <h5>Buttons</h5>

  <p class="u-margin-20-0">Materialize buttons.</p>

  <div class="example grey lighten-3 u-padding-20 u-margin-20-0 u-overflow-hidden u-box-shadow-inset-1">

    <button class="btn left">Button</button>
    <button class="btn left"><i class="material-icons left">add</i>Button</button>
    <button class="btn left"><i class="material-icons right">add</i>Button</button>

  </div>

</div>
```